# How to configure a custom ArcGIS Pro Add-in

Tags: arcgis-pro, add-in

How can ArcGIS Pro add-ins be configured?

I am building an add-in for ArcGIS Pro. This add-in will access external resources via HTTP calls to a SOAP service i have built. I want to be able to "point" the add-in to a specific version of the SOAP service for testing. And then i want to be able to change that configuration.

How can i do this with my add-in?

I would like to avoid having to hardcode the url to the external resource into my built add-in file.

Comment: I would just store an ini/json/text/xml/whatever config file in a well known location, i.e. %APPDATA%/your_addon and then if this file doesn't exist/isn't populated use a hardcoded default (and write that out to the config file) otherwise read the config in and use that. Pretty standard way of doing things.  If your addin has a UI you can also add a settings page if you really want to.